# Retrieving Attachments from RallyDev

Tags: api, rally

Is there a way to retrieve ALL of the attachments from Rally? All of the export options in Rally appear to export only data, not the attachments. I want to be able to export attachments as well.

Does the API support retrieving attachments?

Answer (score 2):

you can get at attachments through the web services api.  You would need to issue a query for the artifacts you want to loop over and then check the Attachments field on that artifact - it should be a collection of attachment artifacts.  This should be documented in the web services api documentation (Help in Rally > Web Services API in the upper right) For example - look at Defect, then look for the Attachments field and the Attachment Type for more information.

Hope that helps.